# Translation for migrated posts in revisions

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration, localization, russian-stackoverflow

I can't find strings to translate for posts which were migrated. E.g:

- [migrated from](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/635642/revisions):

  > [image: from]
- [migrated to](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/482184/revisions):

  > [image: to]

Comment: Related: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5739/15479

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This now looks fixed, but exact translations will be tuned later, at least for Stack Overflow in Russian