# 'No longer needed' flag description isn't localized on ja.SO

Tags: bug, status-completed, comment-flags, localization

On [Japanese Stack Overflow](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/), the description for the 'No longer needed' flag is still in English:

[image]

I've checked other sites (ru.SO, pt.SO) but there it's already in the right language.

Comment: Maybe you should ask on jp.Meta.SO?

Comment: It's new so I'd assume it's just that no one has done the translation yet

Comment: Yes, as Cai says, it just hasn't been translated yet. If no translation is available, it defaults back to English.

Comment: @iBug I'd consider that but my Japenese is limited to 'domo arigato'.

Comment: @iBug most translation issues get reported here (see the ones for ru.so). Depending on if the strings are in Transifex or not it either needs a dev first before a translation can be provided by the community. I think they can stay here and don't need to be on the site meta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Text for localized sites comes from translations database provided by transifex.com. Each unique string that able to localize (translate) from the original English text has a record in transifex DB. If any string is not yet translated localization engine uses original string. Translations is managed by Stack Exchange users who have access to corresponding transifex project (one for each language). If localized site doesn't have translation for some item there are two situations at least:

1. Original string not used in localization engine, i.e. no string in transifex. So translators unable to make translation. Hence it's a SE team bug and should be posted here on MSE. E.g. [Translation for migrated posts in revisions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291903/339911)
2. String exits in transifex, but not yet translated. Hence it's translation team overlook and should be posted as a bug report on the corresponding localized meta site. In particular discussed sentence has been translated for ruSO after posting bug report [Переведите новый интерфейс тревог для комментариев](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5609/176217)

In this way to know the type of localization bug you need to have rights to access transifex project for specific language. Because current sentence is translated on a couple of sites and as far as I know original strings appear simultaneously for different sites there's bug type #2 and should be posted on jpSO.meta.

Comment: Thanks. I agree with your analysis, but there's one problem: I don't speak Japanese and can't post on the site-specific Meta.

Comment: @Glorfindel in this case you can use English language while posting on jpSO.meta I think. Users who are interested on localization issues will understand you.

Comment: I have no doubt about that, but I'd still feel like a 'tourist' there, if you know what I mean.

Comment: @Glorfindel yes, I know :)

Comment: @Glorfindel Well, then what even brought you to ja.SO long enough to click the flag link on a comment? :)

Comment: @AdamLear spam, of course :)

Comment: As it isn't solved yet, I've posted a [バグ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2563/no-longer-needed-flag-description-isnt-localized) on the ja.SO Meta site.