# Unable to translate "to" part for migration notice

Tags: bug, migration, revisions-list, localization, regression

The old [resolved bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291903/339911) is relevant again, but only for ["migrated to"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/482184/revisions) part.

> [image: migrated to]

I can't find that "to" in traducir source strings.

But the better way is to [use full sentence](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305001/339911) to translate instead of the concatenation of parts.

Comment: Not just better, it's necessary (as you allude in the linked post) unless you want the output to be somewhere between "sounds ridiculous" and "written by an illiterate". And even getting to the "sounds ridiculous" tends to be a major PITA when translating things in this manner in many cases.